# How can the icon NEW in SharePoint List be modified?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-foundation

I am not sure if solution to my current issue exists but I have run through the google gamot and nothing has turned up.

I have created a list in SharePoint called Technicians. Please see screenshot:
[image]

This is my first time dabbling into SharePoint.

Employees are required to use this list to sign up for any upcoming event.

Near the top of the screen are three icons, **NEW**, **Quik Edit**, **Export to Excel**

To sign up, the employee must click on the icon **+ NEW**. near top of the screen.

This is not very intuitive. Can this **NEW** icon be modified to say **New Technician**?

Answer (score 0):

1-  **Go to the list form and click on edit page**

[image]

2-  **Click Add a web part**
[image]
3-  **Add content editor web part**
[image]
4-  **Click on the web part then click Edit source button in the Ribbon** 
[image]
5-  **Add the below script** 
change **"New Travel Request"** with your desired name

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
   Sys.Application.add_load(OnListViewLoad);
  function OnListViewLoad() 
  {
      var wpTable = $get("Hero-WPQ2");
      if(wpTable != null)
      {
        var children = wpTable.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = 0; i<children.length;i++)
        {
             if (children[i].getAttribute("id") == "idHomePageNewItem") 
            {
                children[i].children[1].innerHTML = "New Travel Request";
                break;
           }
       }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]
6-  Click on **OK** and then Click **Stop Editing**
[image]
7-  **Now The new button renamed**
[image]

hope this answer be useful

Comment: @ASaeed,

This is awesome stuff. Thanks so much for your assistance.

There is one problem though. There used to be the icon to export to Excel. That has disappeared. Any ideas how to get that back or some nifty workaround?

Comment: @Kenny , was it there before and now missing? if so what's the scenario that made it disappear ?

Comment: @ASaeed, yes it was there before. I was actually able to export data into Excel using that option.

I have no idea what made it disappear. I thought it was the process we used to rename the NEW icon.

In fact, if you look at the screenshot I posted in my original post, you will see the option to Export to Excel. That option is now missing.

Comment: @ASaeed, just as in your examples, the tree buttons are no longer visible.

What I see now are, a, New Walker(that's what I called mine), b, or edit this list.

Then below that, I see All Items followed by three buttons just like yours.

I clicked the buttons, I see, Modify this view or create View. That's it.

Without the Export to Excel option, this is limited even though it is a great piece of work by you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you offered, you are working with SharePoint online and you want to change the icon NEW in a list with modern view.

"Modern" lists and libraries do not support as many customization options as "classic" lists and libraries, so i don't think you can change the icon NEW in modern view.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article about customizing "modern" lists and libraries:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

Comment: you brought up a great point about classic vs modern lists and libraries.

The problem is that when I start making the changes to add the code offered by A Saeed, the only way I was able to do it is to change from classic to modern. Unfortunately, after the change, it doesn't give you the option to go back to modern lists and libraries.

The question then is that I have seen where this change is made using C# code but where does the code go to?

Do you have any idea?